# Retrieve data from firebase in real time

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve data in realtime from my firebase to my app. So, every time I try to change data(like name, ratio, and total_slot) in firebase, it should show it on my app as well in real time. However, it's a bit difficult to get the keys in my firebase structure. If anyone can help though. It would mean so much.

> Attached here is my Firebase data structure
>   [image: Firebase Database Structure]

My Model class

```
public class LocationModel {
    Long lat,lng,ratio,total_slot;
    String name;
    String key;

    public LocationModel(){
    }

    public Long getLat(){return lat;}
    public void setLat(Long lat){this.lat=lat;}

    public Long getLng(){return lng;}
    public void setLng(Long lng){this.lng=lng;}

    public Long getRatio(){ return ratio;}
    public void setRatio(Long ratio){this.ratio = ratio;}

    public Long getTotal_slot(){ return total_slot;}
    public void setTotal_slot(Long total_slot){this.total_slot = total_slot;}

    public String getName() {
        return name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }
    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

How I try to retrieve the data I changed in the firebase

```
//RETRIEVE
public ArrayList<LocationModel> retrieve()
{
    db.child("locs").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            fetchData(dataSnapshot);
            LocationModel locationModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(LocationModel.class);

            locationModels.add(locationModel);

            String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
            mKeys.add(key);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                LocationModel locationModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(LocationModel.class);
                String key = ds.getKey();
                int index=mKeys.indexOf(key);
                locationModels.set(index, locationModel);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
    return locationModels;
}
```

However, everytime I try to change data on my firebase, it gives me an error
Maybe its because of the key. If anyone can help please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Why did you remove the error from the question? This can be very helpfull for helping you resolve this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return dataSnapshot value as a result of a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method)

Comment: Get rid of the children loop on 'onChildChanged' ; the Location object is the child so use fetchData; also the key will now be the same as when you added.  Also , if you implement 'equals' on the Location class to compare "keys" then you dont' need a separate 'mKeys' and you can instead use 'indexOf()' on the 'set' command.  Should still check for -1 just in case.  Btw, the stack trace (found in the edit history) is super useful.

Comment: Also your latitude and longitude values cannot be treated as 'Long's.

Comment: @Andy I did everything that you said and it worked like a charm! Thank you so much for your help! I still used the mKeys though, it doing what its supposed to do. Again, thank you! P.S I'm only getting the name, ratio, and total_slot for my list view. But, lat and lng should be?? Double?

Comment: "But, lat and lng should be?? Double? " .... yes.